# Upload Collection for multiple Employees

Tags: sapui5, multifile-uploader

There is a table with the employee and attach button icon as columns. The requirement is to attachments for each employee, when attach button is clicked, a new window is opened with upload collection UI, and on the close of the window I am saving upload collection to an array and clearing the values of upload collection.

Issue here when I was clearing upload collection, OAttach.files_items is also getting cleared.

How can I achieve this functionality?

I have added below code to save the UploadCollection information for each employee.

```
var oUploadCollection = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idUploadCollection");

OAttach1.push({
                Pernr:lv_attach_Pernr,
                   file_items:oUploadCollection
                });
```

Comment: Try `uploadComplete event`, which is triggered as soon as the upload request is completed with Instant Upload.

Comment: I have Used Upload Complete method only to Clear the OUploadCollection Items , which is also clearing the Items in my OAttach1 Array.